# Looping Inside a list in python

Tags: python, list

So, lets say I have a `secretWord = 'apple'` and I have a list called `lettersGuessed`.

```
lettersGuessed = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
```

This function returns a boolean - `True` if `secretWord` has been guessed (ie, all the letters of `secretWord` are in `lettersGuessed`) and `False` otherwise.

And If I write something like this

```
for c in secretWord:
    matched = [l for l in lettersGuessed if c == l]
    if len(matched) == 0:
        return False

    return True
```

What exactly is happening in `matched = [l for l in lettersGuessed if c == l]`

Comment: open a python interpreter and you could see it for yourself, knowing what happens but why that is another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building a list of all the letters in the list that equal the current character of the secret word, and if that list is empty you deduce that current character hasn't been guessed yet.

Much simpler of course would be

```
return all(c in lettersGuessed for c in secretWord)
```

which, it seems to me, is also more immediately clear to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
matched = [l for l in lettersGuessed if c == l]
```

`c` is every letter in `secretWord`, and `l` is every letter in `lettersGuessed`.  Lets check it part by part;

```
l for l in lettersGuessed
```

This is equal to;

```
for l in lettersGuessed:
    dosomethingwith l
```

So this part returns `l`, other part is checking `if c == l`, so returns `True` if this True. Basically, if `l` matches with `c`.